# SQlite Trigger Execution Problem

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I'm new to Android & SQlite. I was trying to create the following trigger on an SQLite database in Android.

```
final String CREATE_TRIGGER_STATES = 
            "CREATE TRIGGER fk_insert_state BEFORE "
            + "INSERT on tbl_states"
            + "FOR EACH ROW "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'insert on table "
            + "\"tbl_states\" violates foreign key constraint "
            + "\"fk_insert_state\"') WHERE (SELECT id FROM "
            + "tbl_countries WHERE id = NEW.country_id) IS NULL; "
            + "END;";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TRIGGER_STATES);
```

**Error log:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EACH": syntax error: CREATE TRIGGER fk_insert_state BEFORE INSERT on tbl_statesFOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'insert on table "tbl_states" violates foreign key constraint "fk_insert_state"') WHERE (SELECT id FROM tbl_countries WHERE id = NEW.country_id) IS NULL; END;
```

Is there a problem with the syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the relevant portion of the error message is right here:

```
... on tbl_statesFOR EACH ROW ...
//--------------^^
```

You're missing a space after `tbl_states`:

```
final String CREATE_TRIGGER_STATES = 
            "CREATE TRIGGER fk_insert_state BEFORE "
            + "INSERT on tbl_states " // Missing space added
            //... Continue on as before.
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a space:

```
 + "INSERT on tbl_states "    // Space missing here
 + "FOR EACH ROW "
```